# Using async call in mongoose schema pre save function

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I've set up a pre save function for my schema which looks like so:

```
LocationSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  geocoder.geocode(this.address, function ( err, data ) {
    if(data && data.status == 'OK'){
      //console.log(util.inspect(data.results[0].geometry.location.lng, false, null));

      this.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      this.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    }

    //even if geocoding did not succeed, proceed to saving this record
    next();
  });
});
```

So I'd like to geocode a location address and populate the lat and lng attributes before actually saving the model. In the function I posted above the geolocation works but this.lat and this.lng don't get saved. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting those fields in the `geocoder.geocode` callback there so `this` isn't referencing your location instance anymore.

Instead, do something like:

```
LocationSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  var doc = this;
  geocoder.geocode(this.address, function ( err, data ) {
    if(data && data.status == 'OK'){
      doc.lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
      doc.lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
    }
    next();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! So painfully obvious now that you mentioned it.